# Launch Google Chrome into new User Manager on startup

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles, user-management

Recently, Google has introduced a new User Manager feature on the desktop versions of Chrome. It looks a little something like this

[image]

As my parents have to deal with multiple Google accounts, instead of using the "Add account" feature available to Google accounts, I feel it'd be easier for them to use Chrome profiles instead to switch between them. This means I'd like to be able to have Chrome automatically launch into the new User Manager but I can't seem to find a switch that does this. (Only way I know how is to click the User menu and choose `Not <Profile Name>?` or locking the profile.)

Any ideas?